# win1 = window.open and win1.close() in different functions not working

Tags: javascript

I have 2 separate functions in a javascript.

Function one opens a window with

```
win1 = window.open (....);
```

Function two closes the window:

```
win1.close();
```

If those actions are in one function it is working but not in the separate functions as above. It somehow looses the object win1 from one function to another.

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: `win1` must be in a scope accessible by both functions. [Learn more about scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: We can but guess without seeing a testcase. Not psychic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also define `win1` globally:

```
window.win1 = window.open(...);
```

Comment: Global variables should be avoided.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: As should arbitrary generalisations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Global variables should be avoided because the browsers already contain hundreds of names in the global namespace (around 600 in Chrome, for instance). Placing your own names into that namespace introduces a risk of name collisions which in turn produces unexpected results (e.g. your program breaks). As you can see, my advice is not arbitrary. Also, it's not a generalization. Creating custom namespaces in JavaScript is a trivial task. Having your variables exist in your own namespace instead of the global namespace is recommended. This is a fact, not a generalization.

Comment: Great this is working indeed. The global variable is then win1. Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: You're welcome. Read @ŠimeVidas's comments though. You should limit your use of global vars.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I'm not saying that globals should be used here. But, yes, "never use globals" (which is what you're saying, yes?) is a generalisation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I said that global variables should be *avoided*, not that they should never be used. For instance, you want to define one global variable to act as the namespace of your web-application. There may also exist other scenarios where you want to be defining a global variable (I can't think of any right now). So, in certain scenarios it's OK to define one global variable, but the general rule is that global variables should be avoided. Therefore, my initial comment is proper good advice.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: To [avoid](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/avoid) a programming feature means not to use it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Avoid X" means "Don't use X", however it *doesn't* mean "Never use X". If something should never be used, then that will be explicitly stated. When you say "Avoid X", there is room for exceptions, so "X" can be used under fairly exceptional circumstances. Which is pretty much how it applies in this case. Global variables should only be used in fairly exceptional circumstances. Therefore, "avoid using global variables".

Comment: @ŠimeVidas `"Avoid X" means "Don't use X", however it doesn't mean "Never use X"` There is no distinction unless you qualify your statement with a time restriction. I am a native English speaker.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK. I would like to rephrase my original comment: "Use of global variables should be minimized."

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the `win1` variable outside both functions so that they're in the variable scope of both.

```
var win1; // This variable is available in the variable scope of any 
          //    ...functions nested in the current scope.

function f1() {   // This function has access to its outer variable scope
    win1 = window.open();  //  ...so it can access the "win1" variable.

    var foo = 'bar'; // This variable is not available in the outer scope
}                    //   ...because it was declared inside this function.

function f2() {   // This function has access to its outer variable scope
    win1.close(); //  ...so it can access the "win1" variable.

    var bar = 'baz'; // This variable is not available in the outer scope
                     //   ...because it was declared inside this function.

    alert(foo); // Gives a ReferenceError, because "foo" is neither in the
                //   ...current, nor the outer variable scope.
}

f1(); // Invoke f1, opening the window.

f2(); // Invoke f2, closing the window.

alert(foo); // Would give a ReferenceError, because "foo" is in a nested scope.
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I echo win1 inside function f2 it gives: undefined

Comment: @BastiaanWesteinde: Then you're trying to use the variable before it is initialized. You should edit your question to provide the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare a global variable. You can then just use it anywhere in your scripts.

```
var win = window.open("URL"); // or window.win = window
win.open();
win.close();
```

You have to pass win1 as a variable to both functions or have it outside those 2 functions.

```
    function somethingHappened() {
        var url = "http://....";
        var win = window.open(url);

        one(win,url);
        two(win);

    }
function one(win,url) {
        win.open(url);


        }
        function two(win) {
        win.close();

        }
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Both examples use a global var. Can you make your code examples clearer?

Comment: URL depends on the input of the function and needs therefore to be placed inside function one(win)

Comment: I made the necessary changes, i presume the user would like to open a new window based on some event, so i enclosed it in "somethingHappened" function, which would call and pass the win variable

You could pass the url too if you'd like,
function one(win,url) {
win.open(url);
}
and when you call the function , one(win,url) should be passed.